# Case condition does not return desirable results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query:

```
SELECT AccountTitle,
CASE
    WHEN SourceDocDR < 1
        THEN REPLACE(CAST(SourceDocDR AS int), 0, '')
    ELSE SourceDocDR
END AS 'Debit',
CASE
    WHEN SourceDocCR < 1
        THEN REPLACE(CAST(SourceDocCR AS int), 0, '')
    ELSE SourceDocCR
END AS 'Credit'

FROM tblAccounting_GL
WHERE month(PostingDate) = month(getdate())
GROUP BY AccountTitle, SourceDocDR, SourceDocCR;
```

Result with `ELSE` statement:

```
+----------------------------------+---------+--------+
|          Account Title           |  Debit  | Credit |
+----------------------------------+---------+--------+
| Accounts Payable                 | 0.00    | 100.00 |
| Accounts Receivable -VAT         | 0.00    | 300.00 |
| Cash in Bank BPI Mia Road  - PHP | 2600.00 | 0.00   |
+----------------------------------+---------+--------+
```

Result without `ELSE` statement:

```
+----------------------------------+-------+--------+
|          Account Title           | Debit | Credit |
+----------------------------------+-------+--------+
| Accounts Payable                 |       | NULL   |
| Accounts Receivable -VAT         |       | NULL   |
| Cash in Bank BPI Mia Road  - PHP | NULL  |        |
+----------------------------------+-------+--------+
```

The above query should replace zero or negative values by blank. However, it still returns the actual value. If I remove the `ELSE` statement, that's only the time when the zero or negative values are replaced by blanks. However, in that case, all values greater than `0` are not returned also. The above query seems to be perfect for me but I don't know why it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because with the `ELSE` part, the return values gets converted to `DECIMAL` *(or whatever data type `SourceDocDr` has)*. Remember that in a `CASE` expression, if the return values have different data types, they will be converted to the datatype with the higher [data type precedence.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

From the [**`CASE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) documentation:

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in
>   result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

To achieve the desired result, you have to `CAST` the results of the `CASE` expression to `VARCHAR`:

```
SELECT
    AccountTitle,
    CASE
        WHEN SourceDocDR < 1 THEN  ''        
        ELSE CAST(SourceDocDR AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    END AS 'Debit',
    CASE
        WHEN SourceDocCR < 1 THEN ''
        ELSE CAST(SourceDocCR AS VARCHAR(MAX))
    END AS 'Credit'
FROM tblAccounting_GL
WHERE 
    MONTH(PostingDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    AccountTitle, SourceDocDR, SourceDocCR;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this : 
Since you need blank values for zero's and negative value you select blank instead of replacing values

```
  SELECT AccountTitle,
  CASE
    WHEN SourceDocDR < 1
    THEN ''
    ELSE SourceDocDR
 END AS 'Debit',
  CASE
   WHEN SourceDocCR < 1
    THEN ''
   ELSE SourceDocCR
END AS 'Credit'

 FROM tblAccounting_GL
WHERE month(PostingDate) = month(getdate())
GROUP BY AccountTitle, SourceDocDR, SourceDocCR;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this

```
SELECT AccountTitle,
CASE
    WHEN SourceDocDR <= 0
        THEN NULL
    ELSE SourceDocDR
END AS 'Debit',
CASE
    WHEN SourceDocCR <= 0
        THEN NULL
    ELSE SourceDocCR
END AS 'Credit'

FROM tblAccounting_GL
WHERE month(PostingDate) = month(getdate())
GROUP BY AccountTitle, SourceDocDR, SourceDocCR;
```

Your query is type inconsistent, `replace` return string type, but `ELSE` return SourceDocDR, which is number typer. 
Please read more about [`REPLACE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/replace.php)